# Parsing XmlDocument with Variable Parent Tags

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument

Assuming I have an XmlDocument like this:

```
<xmlFile>
  <details>
    <code1>ADJ</code1>
    <code2>ADC </code2>
    <Shipment>
      <foo></foo>
      <bar></bar>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment>
      <foo></foo>
      <bar></bar>
    </Shipment>
  </details>
  <details>
    <code1>ADJ</code1>
    <code2>SCC </code2>
    <Shipment>
      <foo></foo>
      <bar></bar>
    </Shipment>
  </details>
</xmlFile>
```

I need to process each  in an xml file but only shipments that fall under the  tags with a child node  with a value of "ADC". So far I have:

```
// Assume there is an XmlDocument named xml 
XmlNodeList details= xml.GetElementsByTagName("details");

foreach (XmlNode node in details)
{
   if (node["code2"].InnerText == "ADC ")
   {
   // Get each shipment and process it accordingly.
   }
}
```

I can't figure out what to do next. Thanks.

Comment: "Under" = "beneath in text" or "a child of"? (None of the `<codeX>` have meaningful children.)

Comment: Could you use an XDocument and LINQ instead?

Comment: How would you implement it with LINQ and XDocument? The existing code base uses all XmlDocuments.

Comment: Your code2 for the first details is "ADC " not "ADC", so it won't match.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Data\Sample.xml contains xml as mentioned in the question,
Following is the XLINQ query

```
    XElement root = XElement.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"Data\Sample.xml"));
    var adcShipment = root.Descendants().Where(e=>String.Equals(e.Value, "ADC "));
    //next query for nodes/elements inside/next to ADC shipments
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing you're after

```
        XmlNodeList details = xml.GetElementsByTagName("details");

        foreach (XmlNode node in details)
        {
            if (node["code2"].InnerText.Trim() == "ADC")
            {
                // Get each shipment and process it accordingly.
                foreach(XmlNode shipment in node.SelectNodes("Shipment"))
                {
                    var foo = shipment.SelectSingleNode("foo");
                    var bar = shipment.SelectSingleNode("bar");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: For some reason it isn't grabbing the XmlNode shipment when I run the foreach loop. Any thoughts on why it isn't seeing any?

Comment: @ShawnH. Chuck's observation is correct, your XML element value ends in a space character. I have amended the code to ignore this trailing space character. Does it work for you now?

Comment: That was my fault when typing the question. The XML is supposed to have that space. I'll adjust the question.

Answer (score 0):

XPath can simplify your search for matches:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in xml.SelectNodes("/xmlFile/details[normalize-space(code2)='ADC']"))
{
    string foo = node.SelectSingleNode("foo").InnerText;
    string bar = node.SelectSingleNode("bar").InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of adding XPath parsing to this library: https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/

I modified it so you can do this:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
var shipments = root.XPath("details[starts-with(*,'ADC')]/Shipment");
```

Long-hand that looks like:

```
var shipments = root.Elements("details")
                    .Where(x => x.Elements().Any(xx => ((string)xx).StartsWith("ADC")))
                    .Elements("Shipment");
```